# Managing a Ruby application that runs in an infinite loop

Tags: ruby, bash, amazon-web-services

I have a Ruby application that intentionally runs in an infinite loop polling a queue. The application runs in an AWS instance. I launch the application from a bash script. My AWS instance monitor returns a timeout, and shows a red health status, I suspect because my application is in a loop.

How is this sort of scenario handled? should it be handled in the ruby application? or perhaps the bash script that launches it?

Comment: Are you using SQS? What client (right_aws or sqs gem)?

Comment: @Mark - I am indeed using SQS along with the aws-sdk gem

Answer (score 2):

If you have a very tight loop and it's never idle or blocked, it might be possible for it to consume so much CPU that the monitoring fails. I don't think it's likely, but you can test it by stopping the loop and see if that fixes it.

If it does, then add some idle time. If the queue you're checking is in SQS you can specify a wait of up to 45 seconds each time you poll it, so that it blocks for that long or until a message is ready, whichever is first. Otherwise, add a one second sleep every so often - perhaps every time you poll, or every tenth time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Charles! my loop uses SQS Long polling with a wait time of 20. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html

I tried adding a sleep(10) in each poll iteration, still getting red health.

Comment: Well, it was a long shot. Just to check - if you launch the same instance without running the program, does it still show red?

Comment: no it doesn't, as long as I completely remove the old environment using the web interface. With only "eb stop", before an "eb start" I still get red health.